# Add additional fields into doctrine result (DTO)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dto, api-platform.com

Im trying to get the best rated movies by average from my database and hydrate them nicely into a DTO with doctrine so i can work well later with it and integrate them e.g. into my api with api platform.

I already managed to get it work with a raw SQL query but i cannot manage to get it work with hydration into a DTO with doctrine.

```php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Movie;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;

class MovieRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function findBestRated()
    {
        $sql = "
            SELECT m.*, AVG(Cast(r.rating as Decimal)) AS avg_rating, COUNT(r.id) AS count_rating
            FROM `movie` m
            JOIN rating r ON r.movie_id = m.id
            GROUP BY m.id
            ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
            LIMIT 10
        ";

        $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $result = $statement->executeQuery();

        return $result->fetchAllAssociative();
    }
}
```

I would like to use a DTO like below:

```php
namespace App\Dto;

use App\Entity\Movie;

class RatedMovie
{
    public Movie $movie;
    public float $averageRating;
    public int $ratingCount;

    public function __construct(Movie $movie, float $averageRating, int $ratingCount)
    {
        $this->movie = $movie;
        $this->averageRating = $averageRating;
        $this->ratingCount = $ratingCount;
    }
}
```

I found some information on https://geek-week.imtqy.com/articles/en496166/index.html, but still i cannot get the hydration running. I already tried with `ResultSetMapping` and `ResultSetMappingBuilder` and a native doctrine query. With `ResultSetMappingBuilder` i can kind of simulate my raw sql query but the result is still an associative array and not mapped into the `RatedMovie` DTO.

```php
    public function findBestRated()
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->getEntityManager());
        $rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'movieId');
        $rsm->addScalarResult('name', 'movieName');
        $rsm->addScalarResult('avg_rating', 'averageRating', Types::FLOAT);
        $rsm->addScalarResult('count_rating', 'countRating', Types::INTEGER);
        $sql = "
            SELECT m.*, AVG(r.rating) AS avg_rating, COUNT(r.id) AS count_rating
            FROM `movie` m
            JOIN rating r ON r.name_id = m.id
            GROUP BY m.id
            ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
            LIMIT 10
        ";
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

I cannot get it running with `newObjectMappings` or the kind of strange syntax `SELECT NEW DepartmentSalary(d.dept_no, avg_salary) FROM ...` from the linked article. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you tell it to use `App\Dto\RatedMovie`? Also, scalar results will not be translated into entity results https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/native-sql.html#entity-results

Comment: You are right, not in the example that i provided, but this was the only way for me to make it work somehow without raw sql query (still no hydration). But i tried with `SELECT NEW RatedName(AVG(r.rating) AS avg_rating)` and got an error: SQL syntax to use near '(AVG(r.rating) AS avg_rating)…'
Without the NEW Operator Syntax but instead with `$rsm->newObjectMappings['avg_rating'] = ['className' => RatedName::class,…]` the mapping seems not to work, i also got an error: Undefined array key "avg_rating"

Comment: Can you send your MovieOutputDataTransformer?